# A tag [mvcsitemapprovider] não está escrita de maneira incorreta?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tag-específica

Seguindo o conselho do SO abri este post.

> Você está tentando criar a tag [mvc-sitemap-provider](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc-sitemap-provider); no entanto, a tag [mvcsitemapprovider](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvcsitemapprovider) já existe! Se você acha que esta nova tag deve ser permitida, abra um tópico sobre isso em meta

- [Cache por usuário - MVCSiteMapProvider](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/222220/cache-por-usu%C3%A1rio-mvcsitemapprovider)

Observem uma das tags dessa pergunta acima:

[mvcsitemapprovider](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvcsitemapprovider)

Não deveria ser assim (pelo menos), para corrigir, a grafia tudo junta:

[mvc-sitemap-provider](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc-sitemap-provider)

**P.S**: Acho que deveria ser "abra um tópico sobre isso **no** Meta" na sugestão.

Comment: Precisa mesmo dessa tag? É bem específica...

Comment: Eu? Não, porque o downvote não foi meu :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu apaguei a *tag* ruim. E concordo com o bfavaretto que a utilidade dela é pequena, mas não vou decidir nada.